# How to set precision for float in C++

Tags: c++, precision

I want to set precision for float in C++. Suppose my code is

`float a = 23.5, b = 24.36;
float c = a + b;`

and if I print this

```
cout << c;
```

It gives:
46.86

But I want to print till one digit after the decimal point.
How to do that?

Comment: Give a look to this reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You specify the minimum precision by using setprecision. And fixed will make sure there is a fixed number of decimal digits after the decimal point.

```
cout << setprecision (1) << fixed << c;
```

Answer (score 2):

This example may hep you figure it out. You need to read more though about float-point and rounding errors that may occur.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float a = 3.25;

    cout << fixed << setprecision(1) << a;
}
```